# ASP.NET 5 and DocumentDb

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I want to use Azure DocumentDb in my ASP.NET 5 project and it seems that DocumentDb .NET SDK doesn't work with DNX yet. Is it so? And if Yes maybe there is a workaround here?

Comment: A couple of options would be to use the DocDB REST API directly or target full .net framework.

Comment: thanks @AnthonyChu! I've just hoped that someone has created a wrapper for DocDB REST API..

Comment: out of interest @alexxjk, where is this wrapper?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know the status of work on supporting DNX, but assuming that's not going to come in time, I can think of several ways to work around it:

1. Hit the DocumentDB REST API directly
2. Run [edge.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edge) in process inside .NET and use the node.js SDK although there seems to be some question about what platforms are supported by edge.js.
3. Use node.js instead of .NET. My experience helping .NET developers ramp up on DocumentDB has convinced me that the JavaScript-centric design of DocumentDB means, it's much easier to use from node.js than it is from .NET, IMHO. Many of the .NET problems come from the difference between strongly typed .NET and highly dynamic JavaScript. Stored procedures are written in JavaScript not .NET.

Comment: Thank you Larry! I liked the idea with edge.js but apparently .NET Core is not supported by it yet( Correct me if I'm wrong.. I really hope I am)

Comment: I've only run it on .NET 4.5. You could try it relatively quickly I suspect. There is an issue on GitHub asking about 5.0 support but it was never answered.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone .NET is most definitely a first class citizen in the DocumentDB world. Your favoring of one language over another might be due to your preferences when it comes to development languages but that does not mean DocumentDB is better suited to A or B. The LINQ provider supplied in the .NET SDK is feature compatible with the SQL query language.

Comment: @Ryan, I use C# quite a bit and it was my primary language for a long while. All I'm saying is that if you could write stored procedures in .NET as opposed to JavaScript, then the database would be an easier match for .NET client side. Sure, you can hook anything up to anything else, but the amount of adaptation you have to do to bridge the paradigm differences is a burden. Just look at how many questions here on SO for DocumentDB involve marshaling to/from JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You can get ASP.NET 5 to target the full .NET Framework as opposed to Core. The biggest advantage of targeting Core is that it would allow you to run outside of Windows, but if this is not a requirement for you then the full framework should be fine.

Comment: I have finally decided to get my project to target full .NET Framework. for this I I left only one framework in project.json "net46" and I'm not able still to install Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB. is it a right way to switch a framework?